# child div going beyond parent div when used inline-block with nowrap

Tags: html, css, nowrap

```
.containerdiv{
white-space: nowrap;
}

.childdiv{
display : inline-block;
}

<div class="containerdiv">
   <div id="child1" class="childdiv"></div>
   <div id="child2" class="childdiv></div>
</div>
```

I dont want the child div's to wrap. hence created the css as above.

in div "child1" i specify the width which varies in differnt places. to prevent the div child2 going beyond the container i want to specify the max width in child2. ie. not more than the parent div. (i cant calculate and put) how can i achieve this. what i can see is now the div child2 is going out than the parent container. how to prevent this?

please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `#child2` div is missing a closing double-quote on the class definition: `...class="childdiv></div>`.  Should be `<div id="child2" class="childdiv"></div>`

Comment: Hello Axel, Thank you for the reply. that was just a typo, when i entered here. the actual issue is how can i prevent the child div not becoming larger than the container div.

Comment: You should provide a working example of the issue.  The code you've provided isn't going to accurately replicate what you're experiencing.  Create a jsfiddle with the example outcome of the issue.

Comment: Hello Axel, the example is here http://jsfiddle.net/XKpyf/14/   . I want the child div width not to go beyond the container and can't/dont want to specify the width to the child. it is okay to have the child div's text to be truncated.

Comment: and i want to have both the child div's in ONE line.

Comment: So you want the child text to disappear or shorten when the container becomes too small?  Have you tried `overflow: hidden;` on the `.container`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XKpyf/23/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be very happy you can just do inline-block and hope for the best.

BUT if the content is too wide it might just push the inline-block to the next line

**SOLUTIONS**

```
#containerdiv {overflow:auto;}/*the clear fix*/
#containerdiv>div {float:left; width:50%;}
```

There, they both take up 50% of the container and overflow auto clear fixes it.

You can do inline-block with 50% but you need to destroy horizontal whitespace.

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

This works because there is no whitespace between them

```
<div>
<div></div><!--
--><div></div>
</div>
```

This works because the comments remove the whitespace.

Comment: Hello Web Owl, Thank you for the reply. the example is here http://jsfiddle.net/XKpyf/14/ . I am using inline-block and don't want the div to go beyond the parent container without specifying any width to the child as i cant calculate the width, as shown in the example

Comment: Thanks Web Owl, i changed the title. thanks for the suggestion. The purpose i have in a page groups of title and its values in a line. based on the width of the title in the group (max width) i am giving the width ie, the first child div. the width of the container div is in % and is depended on some other outer div's. i want the values to be inside the second child not go beyond the container.

Comment: i checked the solution. Thank you very much. but cant we get something without changing the 100 pixels to 20% ??

Comment: You have the parent set as 50%, that 50% can alter in size depending on the width; it's a %. so having 100px can be DANGEROUS since that 50% is based on % and not px. If it was 300px instead of % than the first child can be 100px and the second can be 200px. I'll see if calc can do something.